# Using && in Circleci yaml file

Tags: circleci

I'am trying to use conditionals in my circleci config file and I can't find any good documentation on how to do it.

This works

```
    if [ "$CIRCLE_TAG" = ""]; then
       // Do something 
    else
      // Do something else
    fi
```

but when i add && and another conditional it doesn't work:

```
if [ "$CIRCLE_TAG" = ""  && "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then
   // Do something 
else
  // Do something else
fi
```

Anyone know of any good resources on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for circleci+yaml+conditionals when i should have searched for bash conditionals. Which is the language circleci uses to execute commands.

the answer was:

```
[[ "$CIRCLE_TAG" = "" && "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" = "master" ]];
```